# galois multiplication by constant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I found this example and couldn't figure how to build the the successive rows of matrix $B$.  I want to understand this example so that I can expand it to $\mathrm{GF}(2^8)$.  I have searched and can't find it answered.

> $\mathrm{GF}(2^6) = \text{binary polynomials modulo} \ x^6 + x + 1$ (a primitive polynomial).  Multiplication by $b = \langle 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 \rangle$ is defined by the matrix $B$ shown below.
>
> The rows of $B$ are $x^i * b$, $i = 0, \dots , 5$, msb on right.
>   Successive rows of $B$ are obtained by shifting previous row right using the feedback pattern $\langle 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 \rangle$ corresponding to $1 + x + x^6$.
>
> $$\begin{align}
> &B = \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 &1 &0 &0 &0& 1 \\
> 1 &0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
> 0 &1 &0 &1& 0& 0 \\
> 0 &0 &1& 0& 1& 0 \\
> 0 &0 &0& 1& 0& 1 \\
> 1 &1& 0 &0& 1& 0 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \\ \implies& \\
> &y_0 = a_0 ⊕ a_1 ⊕ a_5, \\
> &y_1 = a_0 ⊕ a_2 ⊕ a_5,\\
> &y_2 = a_1 ⊕ a_3,\\
> &y_3 = a_2 ⊕ a_4,\\
> &y_4 = a_3 ⊕ a_5,\\
> &y_5 = a_0 ⊕ a_4\\
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> The coefficients $y_0, y_1, \dots , y_5$ of the product $y = a \cdot b = aB$ can be read from columns of $B$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use mathjax in order to make your questions easier to read and thus increase the probability of receiving helpful answers.

Comment: thank you.  I will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$b=1+x+x^5$ (that's what the $<1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1>$ means - they are the coefficients with respect to the basis $1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^5$.  GF(2^6) is (for example) according to this problem $(\mathbb{Z}/2)[x]/(x^6 + x+1)$.  So $x^6 + x+1=0$, so $x^6=-1-x$ and since we are working mod 2 we get $$x^6=1+x$$ in this field. We will use this below to replace $x^6$ by $1+x$ whenever it appears.

The first row corresponds to $x^0 * b=1 \ast b =b$ (note $i=0$) so we get back $b=<1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1>$. The second row takes $i=1$ so we have to calculate $x^1 \ast b$.

$$x \ast b = x(1+x+x^5) =x+x^2 + x^6 = x+x^2 + (1+x) =1+2x + x^2 = 1+x^2$$
and in the basis $1, x, \ldots, x^5$ this corresponds to the vector $(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0).$

The next row $x^2 \ast b = x(x\ast b)=x(1+x^2)$ (from previous step) and so you can get it quickly by shifting the previous row over by one space and introducing a $0$ at the beginning. That works for the next row too. 
For the last row, it's $x$ times the previous row $x^3+x^5$, so $$x(x^3+x^5) = x^4+x^6 = x^4 +(1+x) = 1+x+x^4 $$
so vector is $(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)$ which indeed is the last row.

If you want to generalize it to $GF(2^8)$, you have to find an irreducible polynomial in $(\mathbb{Z}/2)[x]$ of degree $8$.